# vi or vim doesn't start after Cygwin update

Tags: vim, cygwin, vi

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Cygwin Setup: 2.889 (64 bit)

vim: 8.0.1567-1

terminal: mintty 2.8.4

cygwin: 2.10.0-1

I updated cygwin packages on 2018/03/09 and needed to restart OS to complete update. But some services were running so I didn't reboot at that time. In next day I rebooted my windows but found vi/vim command didn't response any more. Even I tried to enter vi, vim or vi -V, vim -v, vim text.txt the terminal only response nothing.

```
$ vi

$
```

I checked vi and vim still exist.

```
$ ls -l `which vi vim`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bobchang None 1014803 三月  5 13:30 /usr/bin/vi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bobchang None 2645011 三月  5 13:30 /usr/bin/vim
```

I checked setup.log vim was erased and installed.

```
2018/03/09 13:31:12    0   erase                    gvim          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    1 install                    gvim          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    2   erase                    vim          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    3 install                    vim          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    4   erase                    vim-common          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    5 install                    vim-common          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    6   erase                    vim-doc          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    7 install                    vim-doc          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    8   erase                    vim-minimal          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:12    9 install                    vim-minimal          8.0.1567-1
2018/03/09 13:31:17 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/preremove/vim.sh"
2018/03/09 13:31:17 Uninstalling gvim
2018/03/09 13:31:17 Uninstalling vim
2018/03/09 13:31:17 Uninstalling vim-common
2018/03/09 13:31:18 Uninstalling vim-doc
2018/03/09 13:31:19 Uninstalling vim-minimal
```

I manually removed and installed vim with related package but helpless.

Do anyone know how to solve this issue or how to debug to find the solution?

**Upldate**
The result of `cygcheck vim` is

```
Found: C:\cygwin64\bin\vim.exe
Found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vim.exe
Found: C:\cygwin64\bin\vim.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\vim.exe
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
        C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-0.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygiconv-2.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygintl-8.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygncursesw-10.dll
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\win32u.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
```

The result of `strace /usr/bin/vim` is `The procedure entry point __memcpy_chk could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\cygwin64\bin\vim.exe.`

```
$ strace /usr/bin/vim
--- Process 5056 created
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 00007ffed9350000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 00007ffed8e10000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 00007ffed6510000
--- Process 5056 thread 10048 created
--- Process 5056 thread 2488 created
--- Process 5056 thread 212 created
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll at 00007ffed8bc0000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygiconv-2.dll at 00000003f4050000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll at 0000000180040000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll at 00007ffed59e0000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll at 00007ffed8390000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygncursesw-10.dll at 00000003f3430000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygintl-8.dll at 00000003f3fa0000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll at 00007ffed5a50000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll at 00007ffed6780000
--- Process 5056 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll at 00007ffed57d0000
--- Process 5056 thread 212 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 5056 thread 10048 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 5056 thread 2488 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 5056, exception c0000139 at 00007ffed9352b10
--- Process 5056 exited with status 0xc0000139
```

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck  vim` ? If no error is reported, you can also run `strace /usr/bin/vim` to see if there is a mismatch in needed libraries.

Comment: @matzeri Thank you very much. I updated my question and you may see the result of two commands. And you are right there is error message but I don't know how to fix it (I don't understand it either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__memcpy_chk` belongs to `cygwin1.dll`

It was added on the last release
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2018-02/msg00002.html

Reinstall the `cygwin` package as it seems was not correctly upgraded.

Comment: Amazing! I reinstalled package `cygwin` and now vim works fine. Thank you very much.